# Where can I see the version of VSC that I have?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to know what version number and year is my VSC. 
Does anyone know where can I see that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open up vsc ( visual-studio-code )
2. click Help tap on top menu
   [image]
3. click about at bottom of drop down menu
   [image]
4. Version number and year are visible there
   [image]

**Release Notes**

To find release year

1. go to help tab
2. click Release Notes
   [image]
3. Here is the release year along with version number
   [image]

Comment: and if that top menu (step 2) is missing, hit the `Alt` key to toggle its visibility